# rpy2.ipython errors with pandas / numpy

Tags: numpy, pandas, ipython, anaconda, rpy2

Trying to use the `rpy2.ipython` (formerly 'rmagic') extension of IPython, to get interactive R (`%R` line magic and `%%R` cell magic functions), I get the following errors...

```
louis ~ $ python
Python 3.5.1 |Anaconda 2.4.0 (64-bit)| (default, Dec  7 2015, 11:16:01) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import rpy2.ipython
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/louis/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pandas import hashtable, tslib, lib
  File "pandas/src/numpy.pxd", line 157, in init pandas.hashtable (pandas/hashtable.c:38262)
  File "/home/louis/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 180, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/home/louis/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/home/louis/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .polynomial import *
  File "/home/louis/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/polynomial.py", line 20, in <module>
    from numpy.linalg import eigvals, lstsq, inv
  File "/home/louis/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/linalg/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from .linalg import *
  File "/home/louis/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 29, in <module>
    from numpy.linalg import lapack_lite, _umath_linalg
ImportError: /home/louis/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/linalg/lapack_lite.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: zgelsd_

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/louis/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rpy2/ipython/rmagic.py", line 59, in <module>
    from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri as baseconversion
  File "/home/louis/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/pandas2ri.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame as PandasDataFrame
  File "/home/louis/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    "extensions first.".format(module))
ImportError: C extension: /home/louis/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/linalg/lapack_lite.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: zgelsd_ not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace' to build the C extensions first.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/louis/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rpy2/ipython/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .rmagic import load_ipython_extension
  File "/home/louis/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rpy2/ipython/rmagic.py", line 63, in <module>
    from rpy2.robjects import numpy2ri as baseconversion
  File "/home/louis/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/numpy2ri.py", line 6, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "/home/louis/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 180, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/home/louis/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/home/louis/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .polynomial import *
  File "/home/louis/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/polynomial.py", line 13, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as NX
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'core'
```

I've always ignored the fact that Anaconda3 seems to have been built on RHEL (I'm on Linux Mint, which is based on Ubuntu), but I'm wondering now if this might be the cause of the problem here - "*C extensions not built*" for my machine?

Since it's in the conda virtual environment, I'm not sure how I can fix this.

Should I attempt to `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` within `~/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas` ?

When I step through the above imports, of e.g. :

```
from numpy.linalg import lapack_lite, _umath_linalg
```

there's no error, so I'm not certain there are actually unbuilt files, perhaps it's just some masking of one variable by another (as in [this question with similar error message but different traceback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33991993/numpy-import-throws-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-core), i.e. an error in `rpy2`).

`import numpy.core` (etc.) without first trying to load `rpy2.ipython` works fine

Summary of `pip show` :

```
---
Metadata-Version: 2.0
Name: rpy2
Version: 2.7.5
---
Metadata-Version: 1.1
Name: numpy
Version: 1.10.1
---
Metadata-Version: 1.1
Name: pandas
Version: 0.17.0
---
Metadata-Version: 2.0
Name: ipython
Version: 4.0.1
```

(all locations `/home/louis/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages`)

System info from `cat /proc/version` and `lsb_release -a` :

```
Linux version 3.13.0-35-generic (buildd@panlong) (gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ) #62-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 15 01:58:42 UTC 2014

LSB Version:    core-2.0-amd64:core-2.0-noarch:core-3.0-amd64:core-3.0-noarch:core-3.1-amd64:core-3.1-noarch:core-3.2-amd64:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch

Description:    Linux Mint 17 Qiana
```

Answer (score 0):

I am suspecting an incompatibility between versions of the LAPACK library: the one picked at runtime on your system, the one numpy was built with, and the one R was built with.

Installing numpy, R, and rpy2 from source in your virtual environment should solve the issue. An alternative would be to notify the maintainers of the anaconda packages involved and see it they confirm that numpy and R packaged by anaconda use the same LAPACK.