# Cannot import some packages in PyCharm

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pycharm, nltk

I installed NLTK package, and i can import NLTK in Jupyter Notebook, but cannot import it in PyCharm.

```
>>> import nltk
>>> import sys
>>> print('\n'.join(sys.path))
```

In jupyter notebook:

```
/Users/morphy/anaconda3/lib/python36.zip
/Users/morphy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6
/Users/morphy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload
/Users/morphy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages
/Users/morphy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aeosa
/Users/morphy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/extensions 
/Users/morphy/.ipython
```

But in Pycharm:

```
/Users/morphy/Documents/workplace/practice
/Users/morphy/Documents/workplace/practice
/Users/morphy/anaconda3/lib/python36.zip
/Users/morphy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6
/Users/morphy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload
/Users/morphy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages
/Users/morphy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aeosa
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/morphy/Documents/workplace/practice/text_classsfier_test.py", line 3, in <module>
    import nltk
  File "/Users/morphy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/__init__.py", line 114, in <module>
    from nltk.collocations import *
  File "/Users/morphy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/collocations.py", line 39, in <module>
    from nltk.metrics import ContingencyMeasures, BigramAssocMeasures, TrigramAssocMeasures
  File "/Users/morphy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/metrics/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from nltk.metrics.scores import          (accuracy, precision, recall, f_measure,
  File "/Users/morphy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/metrics/scores.py", line 18, in <module>
    from scipy.stats.stats import betai
  File "/Users/morphy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
    from numpy import show_config as show_numpy_config
  File "/Users/morphy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/Users/morphy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/Users/morphy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/Users/morphy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/Users/morphy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 74, in <module>
    from numpy.testing.nosetester import _numpy_tester
  File "/Users/morphy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/testing/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from unittest import TestCase
  File "/Users/morphy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/unittest/__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
    from .case import (TestCase, FunctionTestCase, SkipTest, skip, skipIf,
  File "/Users/morphy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 5, in <module>
    import difflib
  File "/Users/morphy/Documents/workplace/practice/difflib.py", line 921
    raise ValueError, 'unknown tag %r' % (tag,)
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The same error is also occurred when i import other packages like numpy and sklearn.

Comment: Please provide the code in your question. An image is not helpful. See here on How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable examplea https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks for you advice! i've already corrected the question.

Comment: Whats inside `text_classsfier_test.py`?

Comment: @VivekKumar just the three lines code: import nltk, import sys, print('\n'.join(sys.path))

Comment: Ok. Then do you have a file called `difflib.py` in your current working directory aside `text_classifier_test.py`. The stack trace says so. See last line of stack trace. And I think thats conflicting with a library level file with same name.

Comment: @VivekKumar Thanks for your reminder. I noticed that i had create a file difflib.py. When numpy is imported, it was calling this file instead of it's own library file hence resulting in the error.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Resolved.

I created a file named difflib.py in my current working directory, hence when numpy is imported, it will call this file instead of it's own library file.

This question is similar to [Numpy import throws AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'core'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33991993/numpy-import-throws-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-core)